# Browse array in Arm 7

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a `src` variable which looks like an array and I would like to iterate through it and store each value one by one in `R5` but I don't know how to go about it.

Can someone help me do this?

Here is my code:

```
        AREA TP2, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY
start
    LDR R0, =src
function
    ...
end_function
    AREA data, DATA, READWRITE
src DCD 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4
    END
```

Comment: I would write the code in C and check what assembly it generates here: https://godbolt.org/. That should give an idea what should be done.

Comment: You also need to either specify the array length or have an 'end marker', otherwise you wouldn't know when to stop iterating.